# Cannot update product attribute field using a csv for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to update my recently uploaded products using a csv. More specifically a  product's custom attribute value. My product is a simple product so I used in my csv the following

```
SKU;Regular price;attribute:pa_mysupplier
```

All other products are updated.
What I am doing wrong

thank you

Comment: You already asked that few hours ago and deleted your thread… If people does not answer your first thread, they will not answer this one more.

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: If I was able I will have already answered… Product attributes are a very complex taxonomy so that's why it doesn't work (each product attribute is a taxonomy, for info)…